# Jetpack social icons in other places on site

Tags: plugin-jetpack, icon

I believe Jetpack is using "Font Awesome" to display social icons. 
This is the css `content: "\f203";` to display facebook for example. If I look in the site source I can't find anywhere the "Font Awesome" being downloaded.

How does this works?

The thing is that I just want to use those icons in my header without making the user download the font again. If I use `content: "\f203";` in my style.css the icon doesn't show.

I have Jetpack active and social icons are displayed on each post.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on Jetpack for font awesome you need to have the CSS files loaded. Best way (in my opinion) to do this is via the CDN.
I use the following:

```
// Add font awesome & bootstrap
function awesome_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style("fontawesome", 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style("bootstrap3", 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'awesome_css' );
```

This goes into your functions.php file.

Then you have a few choices of how to add it. You can use the method you've referred to, or you can use the [fontawesome cheat sheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)

Refer to the examples on fontawesome for more info.

Comment: Ok, but if I use Jetpack and is active and has already loaded the icons how can I use them? I can't understand how can the icons work for jetpack but not in another place on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The font in Jetpack is called social-logos and is used like this : `font: 400 18px/1 social-logos; content: "\f203";`